# Spock exception interaction fails but mockito exception interaction works?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm having a problem with Spock specifications and exception handling.

I have some code that calls a service and catches a certain type of exception. Within the catch block another type of exception is thrown:

```
try { 
   int result = service.invoke(x,y);
   ...
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw BusinessException(e);
}
```

The following test case works using mockito mocks:

```
given: "a service that fails"
def service = mock(Service)
when(service.invoke(any(),any())).thenThrow(new IOException())

and: "the class under test using that service"
def classUnderTest = createClassUnderTest(service)

when: "the class under test does something"
classUnderTest.doSomething()

then: "a business exception is thrown"
thrown(BusinessException)
```

*All Tests Passed*

but the following test case fails when using Spock to handle the interactions of the service:

```
given: "a service that fails"
def service = Mock(Service)
service.invoke(_,_) >> { throw new IOException() }

and: "the class under test using that service"
def classUnderTest = createClassUnderTest(service)

when: "the class under test does something"
classUnderTest.doSomething()

then: "a business exception is thrown"
thrown(BusinessException)
```

*Expected exception of type BusinessException', but no exception was thrown*

I'm not sure what is going on here. It works for mockito but not for Spock.

I'm not verifying the service that throws the exception, so it does not need to be setup in the when/then block.

(using groovy-all:2.4.5, spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example works perfectly fine:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {

    def "simple test"() {
        given:
            def service = Mock(Service) {
                invoke(_, _) >> { throw new IOException() }
            }
            def lol = new Lol()
            lol.service = service

         when:
            lol.lol()
        then:
            thrown(BusinessException)
    }
}

class Service {
    def invoke(a, b) {
        println "$a $b"
    }
}

class Lol {
    Service service 

    def lol() {
        try {
            service.invoke(1, 2)
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new BusinessException(e)
        }
    }
}

class BusinessException extends RuntimeException {
    BusinessException(Exception e) {}
}
```

Maybe you've misconfigured something?

Comment: It's weird ... I reverted back to using Spock interactions and the code now works. Gremlins. Will delete the question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Maybe it was a classpath issue? I'd rather leave it as is, along with my answer - for future askers. It's a complete example.